# How to perform some tasks in the previous item in VerticalPager?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to know If I want to perform any task in the previous Item in the Vertical Pager how can I do this?
Like If I want to send some events from the backend when the page is scrolled or in the background or I want to pause the video?

In the viewPager2 we can use fragments and we have the lifecycle of each fragment to perform such tasks in the lifecycle methods. I just want the same functionality in the VerticalPager.